# How can I taking apart a string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a pattern like this:

```
[X number of digits][c][32 characters (md5)][X]

/* Examples:
2 c jg3j2kf290e8ghnaje48grlrpas0942g 65
5 c kdjeuw84398fj02i397hf4343i013g44 94824
1 c pokdk94jf0934nf0932mf3923249f3j3 3
*/
```

**Note:** Those spaces into those examples aren't exist in the real string.

I need to divide such a string into four parts:

```
// based on first example
$the_number_of_digits = 2
$separator            = c // this is constant
$hashed_string        = jg3j2kf290e8ghnaje48grlrpas0942g
$number               = 65
```

How can I do that?

---

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
/^(\d+)(c)(\w{32})/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pF8oP7/1)

My pattern cannot get last part.

---

**EDIT:** I don't want to select the rest of number as last part. I need a algorithm based on the number which is in the beginning of that string.

Because maybe my string be like this:

```
2 c 65 jg3j2kf290e8ghnaje48grlrpas0942g
```

Comment: Are there spaces in your data or not?

Comment: @RocketHazmat There isn't any space.

Comment: imo, maybe interesting? [unpack — Unpack data from binary string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php). Why? i,o, everything is fixed length and position. If so, it will be fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that one match drives the length of another match suggests that you will need something a bit more complicated than a single expression. However, it need not be that much more complicated: `sscanf` was designed for this kind of job:

```
sscanf($code, '%dc%32s%n', $length, $md5, $width);
$number = substr($code, $width, $length);
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/13X6M).

The trick here is that `sscanf` gives you the width of the string (`%n`) at exactly the point you need to start cutting, as well as the length (from the first `%d`), so you have everything you need to do simple string cuts.

Answer (score 4):

This regex uses named groups to access the results:

```
(?<numDigits>\d+) (?<separator>c) (?<hashedString>\w{32}) (?<number>\d+)
```

*edit*: (from @RocketHazmat's helpful comments) since the OP wants to also *validate* that "number" has the number of digits from "numDigits":

> Use the regex provided then validate the length of number in PHP. if(
>   strlen($matches['number']) == $matches['numDigits'] )

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vF2mW3/1) output (your string as input):

[image]

Comment: How does this work? It doesn't seem like you are using `numDigits` so how does it capture the correct number of characters?

Comment: @Andrew: It doesn't capture the *correct* number of characters.  This is the *same* as [@Clint's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37356718/206403) except the groups are named instead of numbered.  The only difference is that in PHP, you can do `$matches['hashedString']` instead of `$matches[3]`.

Comment: It is not using the first match to guide the second. As Rock Hazmat points out,  regex doesn't have that kind of logic built in - I thought the OP just wanted to match the segments.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ok fine.. is there any non-regex approach?

Comment: @stack: Use the regex provided then *validate* the length of `number` in PHP.  `if( strlen($matches['number']) == $matches['numDigits'] )`.  You may also want to add the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: `\w` will match `_`, not included in a md5 hash.

Answer (score 1):

Add `(\d+)` to the end, like you have in the beginning.

```
/^(\d+)(c)(\w{32})(\d+)/
```

Comment: Wrong ..! Actually if I want to do that like you, It would be better to add `$` in the end of your pattern. But I don't want this algorithm. I need a algorithm based on the length of that number at the beginning of that string.

Comment: @stack: I don't think regular expressions can be *that* dynamic.  You may have to check that length in PHP.

Comment: @stack I see, I missed that information in the question.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Well please take a look at answer below .. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

```
/(\d)(c)([[:alnum:]]{32})(\d+)/
```

---

```
preg_match('/(\d)(c)([[:alnum:]]{32})(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
$the_number_of_digits = $matches[1];
$separator            = $matches[2];
$hashed_string        = $matches[3];
$number               = $matches[4];
```

Then, to check if the string length of `$number` is equal to `$the_number_of_digits`, you can use [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php), i.e.:

```
if(strlen($number) ==  $the_number_of_digits){

}
```

---

The main difference from other answers is the use of `[[:alnum:]]`, unlike `\w`, it won't match `_`.

---

```
[:alnum:]
```

> Alphanumeric characters: ‘`[:alpha:]`’ and ‘`[:digit:]`’; in the ‘`C`’
>   locale and ASCII character encoding, this is the same as
>   ‘`[0-9A-Za-z]`’.

http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html

---

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iF4vY7/2)**

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/tPp0LE)

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
(\d)(c)([[:alnum:]]{32})(\d+)

Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d)»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(c)»
   Match the character “c” literally (case insensitive) «c»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «([[:alnum:]]{32})»
   Match a character from the **POSIX** character class “alnum” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, other number) «[[:alnum:]]{32}»
      Exactly 32 times «{32}»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «(\d+)»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```